# React Router v4 for GET method - returns Router and not REST call

Tags: express, webpack, react-router, react-redux, superagent

I'm using react router v4 ("react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"), and express ("express": "^4.14.1"). 
I have very strange behavior. POST calls are working fine, but for GET call, the REST call is not getting proceed to express, but getting back simple HTML in the response.
There is wired WA... if the REST url contains dot (.), then it works fine..

Router code:

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Internationalization/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={LoginPage}/>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage}/>
                    <PrivateRoute isAuthorized={true} path='/businessRequestPage' component={BusinessRequestPage}/>
                    <Route path='*' component={LoginPage} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

Express code:

```
function createFixtureServer(port) {
let express = require('express');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let router = express.Router();

defineRoutes(router);

app.use('/', router);

app.listen(port);

console.log('Fixture server is up. port -> ', port);
return app;
```

Web pack config:

```
devServer: {
    hot: true,
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 9000,
    proxy: {
        '/*': {
            target: 'https://localhost/',
            secure: false
        }
    }
```

It works for example to that URL:
**router.get('/v1.0/general-details/:name', getGeneralDetails);**
But not working for that URL (not getting to express):
**router.get('/v1/general-details/:name', getGeneralDetails);**

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Look at your routes. Express probably defines root route path of the API as `v1.0` and not `v1`

Comment: Dot somewhere in the url is working, for example '/aaa/bbb/.' will work, but 'aaa/bbb/' will not work. And only for GET